# alfresco : restore a previous version loses the metadata

Tags: version, alfresco, document, restore

I use Alfresco 5.0.d,
When I go back to an older version of a document, the metadata of the document are lost.
Is there a way to ask alfresco to keep the metadata when I change version?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, you'd like to keep the current version of the metadata (the most current one), and just revert the content, am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: is that possible? if so that will be great for me